# Trying to compare two lists c# - Should work?

Tags: c#, list, compare, sequence

I have a method that looks like this:

`GetDrawing(Dictionary<string, List<string>> AllDrawings, Dictionary<string, bool> ImportData, string[] ItemsToCompare)`

Firstly, the method creates a new `List<string>` with all the items from `ImportData<string, bool>` that have the value `true` and can be found in `string[] ItemsToCompare`

Secondly, I would like to compare the new `List<string>` with the List from `AllDrawings<string, List<string>>`. The method is in the end supposed to return a string with the key from `AllDrawings<string>, List<String>>` where the two lists match.

I have now spent a lot of hours trying to figure this out myself and also tried every answer I could find to similar questions here on Stackoverflow but with no luck.

Below is the full code for my method. As mentioned above I've tried a lot of different methods to compare the lists but the one following below is the latest try.

```
  public static string GetDrawing(Dictionary<string, List<string>> AllDrawings, Dictionary<string, bool> ImportData, string[] ItemsToCompare)
    {
        string FinalDrawing = "";
        try
        {
            List<string> AllCorrect = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in ImportData)
            {
                if (item.Value == true && ItemsToCompare.Contains(item.Key))
                    AllCorrect.Add(item.Key);
            }

            AllCorrect.Sort();

            foreach (var DrawItem in AllDrawings)
            {

                DrawItem.Value.Sort();
                var match = AllCorrect.SequenceEqual(DrawItem.Value);

                if (match == true)
                {
                    FinalDrawing = DrawItem.Key;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return FinalDrawing;
    }
```

My problem is that the return value from `var match = AllCorrect.SequenceEqual(DrawItem.Value);` is `false` and therefore the `FinalDrawing` is never set.

All answers are very appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"The method is supposed to create a new List<string>"* but your example method returns `string` - which is it?

Comment: @Jamiec Sorry, that was misleading. It's edited now. The return type is not that important as I need help with the comparison of the lists but you are absolutely right that my question should be consistent.

Comment: Your `AllCorrect` looks fine. Also, sorting it and sorting `DrawItem.Value` and `SequenceEquals` looks fine (assuming no lowercase/uppercase mismatch) (although, I just read it, not tried running). So, what issue do you have with all of that actually?

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl I also think it should work. Unfortunately the return value from `var match = AllCorrect.SequenceEqual(DrawItem.Value);` is `false` and therefore the `FinalDrawing` is never set.

Comment: As a comment, if a method does two things, it's one to many. Split it up, and go from there. Test if the smaller ones doing what you expect them to be doing. Continue from there.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl - Of course. Edited now :) 

@Martijn - I've already tried to split it up and controlled the output from each list and they are exactly the same when they SHOULD match but still `bool match` returns `false`

Comment: Olivier - have you inspected the contents of those strings? Maybe they are a little different. Could you add some samples of input data? especially one or two `imported` and some of the `alldrawings` thatyou expect to be the match for them

Comment: DrawItem.Value is unsorted List<string>, AllCorrect is sorted List<string>. As i know, SequenceEqual  uses standard enumerator methods to get next item, your comparison will fail. Instead of List<T>Sort(), OrderBy will return new ordered list for DrawItem.Value, if you can't change data in AllDrawing

Comment: You've answered your own question; your sequences are clearly *NOT* equal.

Comment: @vitalygolub: have you missed `DrawItem.Value.Sort();`? [It will sort that `List<string>` in-place](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.100).aspx), so that list is actually sorted.

Comment: Sorry, really missed,  was dumbfounded with if (match == true) :-). Tried your code in test application, real problem is - when math is true, your function will not return and  continue search, but  this absolutely no effect on the result, the function returns key anyway. Strings exactly are different, are not interned literals, but generated in for cycles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code :

```
        List<string> AllCorrect = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in ImportData)
        {
            if (item.Value == true && ItemsToCompare.Contains(item.Key))
                AllCorrect.Add(item.Key);
        }

        AllCorrect.Sort();
```

Can be reduced to :

```
     List<string> AllCorect = ImportData.Where(vp => 
       ItemsToCompare.Contains(vp.Key) && vp.Value).Select(vp => vp.Key).OrderBy(vp => vp).ToList();
```

To solve the second problem you can do :

```
return AllDrawings.First(l => l.Value.OrderBy(l2 => l2).SequenceEqual(AllCorect)).Key;
```

P.S.
If `First()` always throws an exception then it suggests that problem lays in how this lists are filled with values and this is a different question.

Example :

```
    public static string GetDrawing(Dictionary<string, List<string>> AllDrawings, Dictionary<string, bool> ImportData, string[] ItemsToCompare)
    {
        List<string> AllCorect = ImportData.Where(vp => 
           ItemsToCompare.Contains(vp.Key) && vp.Value).Select(vp => vp.Key).OrderBy(vp => vp).ToList();

        return AllDrawings.First(l => l.Value.OrderBy(l2 => l2).SequenceEqual(AllCorect)).Key;
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> list1 = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three" };
        List<string> list2 = new List<string>() { "five", "six", "seven" };

        Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
        {
            {"first", list1}, {"second", list2}
        };

        string[] itemsToCompare = { "one", "two", "three" };

        var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, bool>()
        {
            {"one", true},
            {"two", true},
            {"three", true}
        };

        var result = GetDrawing(dict, dict2, itemsToCompare);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

Output : `first`

Comment: I love linq and my reaction was like that too, until I read that code and until I read the question is about: `(...) the return value from var match = AllCorrect.SequenceEqual(DrawItem.Value); is false and therefore the FinalDrawing is never set.`. If SeqEqls does not match, it does not match. Answer to OP's problem should address that not just squash the code with linq.

Comment: True. Which means the OP should already have their answer - their sequences are *not* equal!

Comment: @Jamiec - But they are equal. Even when I add my own examples with data like { "one", "two" } it returns false. I am currently constructing some examples for you, unfortunately I can´t post the current data I use as it´s classified by my company.

Comment: @Oliver - if they were equal it would return true - like this: http://rextester.com/VNPSY41217

Comment: @Oliver I've updated my answer with example. It works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Ok.. I already said that in comments, but just to make sure that you don't get yelled at too much for not-using-linq and such:

**your program seems correct up to the point you told us.**

Here's a simple test. I provided some stub data that cover all things that you seem to check:

- only `true` things from importedata
- only things that are listed in itemstocompare
- input lists are not sorted

-> http://rextester.com/HAE73942

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    // your original function, nothing changed
    public static string GetDrawing(Dictionary<string, List<string>> AllDrawings, Dictionary<string, bool> ImportData, string[] ItemsToCompare)
    {
        string FinalDrawing = "";
        try
        {
            List<string> AllCorrect = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in ImportData)
            {
                if (item.Value == true && ItemsToCompare.Contains(item.Key))
                    AllCorrect.Add(item.Key);
            }

            AllCorrect.Sort();

            foreach (var DrawItem in AllDrawings)
            {

                DrawItem.Value.Sort();
                var match = AllCorrect.SequenceEqual(DrawItem.Value);

                if (match == true)
                {
                    FinalDrawing = DrawItem.Key;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return FinalDrawing;
    }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var allDrawings = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            allDrawings.Add("aaa", new List<string>{ "a03", "a01", "a02" }); // originally unsorted
            allDrawings.Add("bbb", new List<string>{ "b03", "b01", "b02" }); // originally unsorted
            allDrawings.Add("ccc", new List<string>{ "c03", "c01", "c02" }); // originally unsorted

            var import = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
            import.Add("b01", false); // falsey
            import.Add("a05", true); // not in comparison
            import.Add("a03", true);
            import.Add("c01", false); // falsey
            import.Add("a02", true);
            import.Add("a04", true); // not in comparison
            import.Add("a01", true);

            var toCompare = new string[9];
            toCompare[0]="a01"; toCompare[1]="a02"; toCompare[2]="a03";
            toCompare[3]="b01"; toCompare[4]="b02"; toCompare[5]="b03";
            toCompare[6]="c01"; toCompare[7]="c02"; toCompare[8]="c03";

            var result = GetDrawing(allDrawings, import, toCompare);

            Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result);
        }
}
```

it works fine and prints `aaa` as it should.

This means that you had to have overlooked something in the input data. Maybe some strings are uppercase/lowercase? Maybe some strings have whitespaces inside and others not?

Comment: You were right. I went back and checked my entire code and I found out that I had another method that I use to split strings which interfered with this one. That's why it worked alone but however I tried it in my program it turned out false. Thank you for confirming that my code actually worked, that gave me the push to go through all my other code.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't accept two answers.. But thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

If the strings really match also for casing your code would be correct. I propose you inspect your string sequences - create an readable string and add appropriate break points. Also try to sort case-insensitive if that is what is missing here

```
    AllCorrect.Sort(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    var AllCorrectInfo = string.Join(", ", AllCorrect.ToArray());
    foreach (var DrawItem in AllDrawings)
    {

        DrawItem.Value.Sort();
        var DrawItemInfo = string.Join(", ", DrawItem.Value.ToArray());

        var match = AllCorrect.SequenceEqual(DrawItem.Value, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        if (match == true)
        {
            FinalDrawing = DrawItem.Key;
        }
    }
```